# What is the difference in heapify and heappush? which is better?

Tags: python, heap

heapify and heapush both putting the minimum item on top and lowest items are in correct place. I do not understand what is the difference and usage difference

```
import heapq
H = [21,1,45,78,3,5]
# Covert to a heap

# Add element
heapq.heappush(H,-100)
heapq.heappush(H,-98)
heapq.heappush(H,-1)
print(H)
heapq.heapify(H)

print(H)


# output: [-100, -98, 21, -1, 3, 5, 45, 78, 1]
# [-100, -98, 5, -1, 3, 21, 45, 78, 1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple differences between `heappush` and `heapify`.

1. `heappush` assumes that the array (`H` in your case) is already a heap. `heapify` does not--`H` merely needs to be a list. Note that in your example, your data structure `H` is not a heap before you execute the three `heappush` commands. (For example, `H` begins as `[21,1,45,78,3,5]`, but the first item `21` is greater than the second item `1`, which violates the definition of a heap.) As a result, `H` is not a heap after the `heappush` commands either. (`H` becomes `[-100, -98, 21, -1, 3, 5, 45, 78, 1]` but the 3rd item `21` is larger than the 6th item `5`, which also violates the definition of a heap.) After the `heapify`, the `5` and `21` items have swapped places and `H` is then a correct heap.
2. `heappush` adds a new value to the heap. `heapify` does not add a value--it rearranges the values in the list.
3. You could build a heap by creating an empty heap then calling `heappush` for each item you want to add, or you could make a list of the items in any order then calling `heapify` on the list. The `heappush` method will have time complexity O(n * log(n)) where `n` is ending size of the heap, while the `heapify` method will have complexity O(n), which is significantly lower. As an example, if you are creating a heap with one million items, the `heappush` method can use up to on the order of `20,000,000` operations while the `heapify` method uses only at most on the order of `1,000,000` operations. That is a factor of `20` difference. Of course, the operations are not exactly the same and the actual numbers are a little different, so the actual factor will be different, but `heapify` will almost certainly be faster.
4. The `heappush` method of building a heap requires many individual statements or a loop of some kind to add the items. The `heapify` method merely requires the list to exist. Therefore the `heapify` method will most probably use fewer code lines and less code complexity. (Adding a `for` loop to your code adds another level of complexity, which can lead to more bugs.)

In conclusion, doing `heapify`on a list is almost always a better choice than creating an empty list and adding many items with `heappush`. If you just add a few items, `heappush` may be better.

Comment: Thanks Rory. Great explanation. I am little confused in complexity though. O(log(n)) is not less than o(n) ? then how heappush is slow ?

Comment: @Atarnew: Oops, I made a typo. That should be O(n * log(n)). I just corrected that.

Comment: Thanks Rory.Great answer.

Comment: Why is heapify O(n)?

Comment: @Soubriquet: A full explanation is either lengthy or has complicated math. For the math, see [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/time-complexity-of-building-a-heap/]. (The 'heapify' function at that site is different than Python's: it means to correct one chain in the heap where only the top item may be out of place. The time complexity of their 'heapify' is just O(log(n))).

Comment: @Soubriquet: For a shorter, incomplete explanation, note that about half the items in the list are at the very bottom of the complete binary tree and are complete heaps in themselves so need no action. The next-to-bottom layer as about 1/4 the items and needs only 1 operation to link them to the bottom layer. And so on, until only the top layer, with one item, needs to be linked to log(n) items. In other words, most items need very little processing, while few items need much processing. The entire process takes about 2n actions, which is O(n). Is that clear?

Comment: That explanation makes sense, but does the Python heapify api mention explicitly that it's O(n)?

Comment: @Soubriquet: The Python Standard Library documentation, at https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html, says this about heapq.heapify(x): "Transform list x into a heap, in-place, in linear time." That "linear time" phrase means O(n). So yes, it does mention that explicity.